# Rails - Trouble Using Ajax on Like Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a little trouble with using AJAX on something I've done before with no issues, but this site has a few different configurations which are causing trouble for me. The main problem I'm having, is when I click the `Like` link on a post, all of the `like` links on that page are changed to `unlike`, even though the one I clicked is the only one getting posted in the Database.

On my user's profile page (`users/show.html.erb`), I'm showing all of the posts (`updates` in this scenario) that the particular user has posted.

Here is my configuration thus far:

**Users Controller, Show Action**

```
def show
  @updates = @user.updates.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

**Updates Controller, Like Action**

```
def like
  begin
    @vote = current_user.vote_for(@update = Update.find(params[:id]))
    if @vote.save
      respond_with @update.user, :location => profile_path(@update.user)
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    redirect_to @update
  end
end
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="like_button">
  <%= render :partial => 'updates/like_button', :locals => {:update => update} %>
</div>
```

**updates/_like_button.html.erb Partial**

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(update) %>
  <%= link_to unlike_update_path(update), :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
    <i class="ss-heart liked" title="Unlike Update"></i>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to like_update_path(update), :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
    <i class="ss-heart animate" title="Like Update"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**updates/like.js.coffee**

```
$(".like_button").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'updates/like_button', :locals => {:update => @update} %>");
```

So just to refresh, the like button works and records the `vote` into the database, but it changes all of the like_buttons on the page to appear as if they have been liked instead of just the one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to distinguish your like buttons (by css class / id for example) and then you can alter them with jQuery concretely

```
$(".like_button").html("<%= escape_javas...
```

while currently `$(".like_button")` aims for all elements with that .like_button class (which are all).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow...can you elaborate please?

Comment: There is - as far I can see - not a single line or something which would solve your problem. What does your like button like? If it's a model itself, perfect, then add id="like_<%= @like.id %>" to your .like_button element and change your like.js.coffe (which I assume is meant to be a like.js.erb?) into $("#like_<%= @like.id").html...